# Загрузка файла с сервера

Tags: php

Помигите организовать загрузку файла. Что я только не перпробывал, но браузер настойчиво пытается открыть файл, а не скачать.

Comment: Так:

    <?php

    header();

    ?>

Comment: вы о header('Location: '.$fileName)? как ни странно редирект не работает вообще. Тоесть игнорируется абсолютно, как будто там его и нет. 
header('Location: http://ya.ru') -даже на это ноль эмоций..

Comment: Вообще-то не редирект, а указание типа файла, чтобы отдать его на скачку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$file = '/path/to/file.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.jpg"');
readfile($file);
```

Имя файла и Content-type указываете для своего конкретного файла.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file_name=$myrow['file'];
  header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file_name));
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name); 
  header("Content-Type: application/x-force-download; name=\"".$file_name."\"");
 dfile($file_name);
```

качает файлы любого расширения